# Border width not working

Tags: html, css

How can I change bottom border width?

Here is some my code:

```
h6 {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    border-bottom-width: 30%;
    color: #858585;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Border width can't be a percentage. Percentage of what? If you want it percentage of the element itself you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: I think the reason you got down votes for this question is that you don't explain what it is you're trying to achieve which left people to guess. Perhaps you could edit it to make this clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use percentage borders but one thing you can do is create a fake border by using a div. So your html might look like:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h6>Title</h6>
</div>
```

And your css:

```
h6 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #858585;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.wrap {
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    background-color: #D6D6D6;
    margin: 40px;
}
```

EDIT: here's a jsfiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/QR3pL/

EDIT 2: You don't really explain what you're trying to achieve but it occurs to me you might have misunderstood the border width property. It can be better thought of as a the thickness of a border. If you want to set the horizontal length (which I think is what chiefGui assumed) then that is trickier but can again be faked.

Here's some html:

```
<h6>A Title goes here</h6>
```

And here's the css:

```
h6 {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #858585;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h6:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EEfYQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Defining border width in `%` is not valid you have to use `px`, `em`, `rem`, `in`, `cm` or something else...

Comment: Pfu... not weight, but lenght

Comment: you can not change lenght of border border will always be as long as it needs to be to wrap element

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the width in `%` - use `px` or a relative unit like `em`.

Whether you use

```
border-bottom: 5px solid #D6D6D6;
```

or

```
border-bottom-width: 3em;
```

doesn't matter though. Both works.

Answer (score 0):

You will define the border length with the `h6` width — not with a isolated rule.

Try to set a **width** for the `h6` element rule:

```
h6 {
    width: 30%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

[I have illustrated the situation here, on FiddleJS.](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/gGS9c/1/)

But use carefully, because all the content of `h6` rule will contain 30% of width.

Comment: He is not questioning about the thickness of the border, but about the length. I have illustrated to him how works — that is different from what he thinks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the official definition of "border width"... http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-width-properties

Comment: I know what "border width" means. It is exactly what I'm talking about. `border-width` is not the solution for him. [Take a look here](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/gGS9c/3/)